# Changing Column Ordinal_position Positions

Tags: sql, t-sql

My scenario:

I can change the ordinal position of a column in a table.Is there a way to change the ordinal position of a column in a table without recreating the table?

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you have to recreate the table if you wish to achieve this. (SQL SERVER)

Even when you do this in SSMS, you will see that the script that is generated also recreates the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not in SQL Server - Not sure about other RDBMSs.

You can create a View with the desired ordinal positions but the only time I can think that would be useful is if you are using `SELECT *` which is a practice that should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it depends on the database system you use.
For example in some it is possible to remove and add a column and you can do it in a procedure part where you also  can refill it.

But in general it shouldn't matter as you can define the returned data order in your select statement. Is not that enough for you?

Comment: it matters when you are using temporal tables

Answer (score 0):

Without recreating the Table is Not possible. However, if your concern is about loosing the data here is an option provided by SQl Server Management Studio.

**Note:** I have used Sql Server 2019 Developer Edition.

1. Right Click on the Table name and Choose **Design** Option
2. Using your Cursor Drag the position of your Column to your desired Position

[SQlServer Table Design Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WH6R.png)

If you want to do it at script level, You can see the idea below provided by SSMS

Enable the "Auto Generate Change Script" Option available in Tools Menu --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers.

[Enabling the Auto Generate Change Script Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWkvS.png)

When you drag the Column in SSMS it will automatically creates the Script for you.

The High level Idea in the auto generated Script is,

1. Creating a Table with Temp_YourTableName with desired Order of Columns
2. Copying all the Data from the Original Table to new Temp_YourTableName
3. Drop the Original Table
4. Renaming the Temp_YourTableName to Original YourTableName

of course doing everything with Transaction scope to avoid any data loss while the script is executing.

I found a good reason why some time we need to do this [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1994327.aspx?How%20to%20change%20the%20ORDINAL_POSITION%20of%20column%20in%20specific%20table). Interestingly, it is based on Context and not to do anything with Technical.

Say for example, Original Address Table Contains, Street Address 1, City, State, Zip and Country columns. If the requirement Changes to include a new Columns like Street Address 2 this would be meaning full.